# How to push Ecommerce Transactions to GTM Data Layer

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, data-layers

I'm pushing some tags to the data layer and they all seem to be working as expected except for ecommerce transaction data. I have confirmed that the transaction data *is* being pushed to the data layer but for some reason I'm not seeing any results in Google Analytics—even after waiting 48 hours.

I should mention that this is an [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) so there is no page refreshing. The data is pushed to the data layer after the payment is successfully processed.

This is the data I'm sending:

```
{
  event: 'subscribe',
  user: <USER_ID>,
  subscribe: {
    transactionId: <CUSTOMER>,
    transactionAffiliation: <AFFILIATION>,
    transactionTotal: <PRICE>,
    transactionProducts: [
      {
        id: <CUSTOMER>,
        sku: <SUBSCRIPTION>,
        name: <PLAN>,
        price: <PRICEPER>,
        quantity: <QUANTITY>
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Is there something wrong with the way I'm formatting this? Any ideas why this doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using the custom event "subscribe" instead of the standard `"event":"checkout"` key?

Comment: Because the former is like voodoo magic to configure and the latter just kinda works.

Comment: So you think I should just use 'checkout'? That was one concern I had.

Comment: I noticed 'checkout' as an event name for enhanced ecommerce setup but wasn't sure how standard ecommerce was supposed to work. Should I use 'checkout' as the event name or as the key name for my transaction data or both?

Comment: When are you pushing that data to the DL? I'm assuming when someone clicks on a "subscribe" button?

Comment: @XTOTHEL When the user clicks the subscribe button, I process the form and submit the payment. When the payment request returns successfully (200) then I push the transaction to the Data Layer.

Answer (score 0):

For just regular NOT enchanced ecomm, you need to make some adjustments to your datalayer first:

```
{
  event: 'subscribe',
  user: <USER_ID>,
  transactionId: <CUSTOMER>,
  transactionAffiliation: <AFFILIATION>,
  transactionTotal: <PRICE>,
  transactionProducts: [{
        id: <CUSTOMER>,
        sku: <SUBSCRIPTION>,
        name: <PLAN>,
        price: <PRICEPER>,
        quantity: <QUANTITY>
  }]
};
```

Then create a **custom event trigger** referencing the `subscribe` event:
[image]

Then create a GA tag and select **Track Type** of **Transaction**, elect your GA settings variable and set the trigger to that custom event trigger we created above:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @XTOTHEL, I'll give that a shot and let you know if 48 hours.